# list files in a directory - and filter results

Tags: c, posix

I am trying to implement a "ls" as a back to basic training. I know I can use `opendir()` and `readdir()` to do the basic listing.

For sorting - I have no option, but to add each entry into a an array - and sort.
For filtering - or globbing - I assume I can manually do this in my code. But I am looking for "not trashing the disk" - and let the OS filter this for me. Also - filtering "$234*.a*" is not trivial.

Question:
How can I list all "*.txt" files in a directory in good old C? (Unix/Posix only, that is OK).

Sources for inspiration:
https://github.com/dosbox-staging/dosbox-staging/blob/master/src/shell/shell_cmds.cpp#L656
https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/ls.c#L1206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For filtering - or globbing - I assume I can manually do this in my code

Do not reinvent the wheel - [glob](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/glob.html) and [fnmatch](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fnmatch.html) and [wordexp](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html) are standard.

> How can I list all "*.txt"

The expansion of `*.txt` globbing is done by your shell as part of [filename expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_06) and are spitted into separate arguments *before* executing the `ls` command. Expanding globbing expressions is not part of `ls`. Supporting globbing in `ls` would be a non-standard extension.

To list files in a directory, use [scandir](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alphasort.html) (with `alphasort`). A perfect example of `scandir` is in [linux man pages scandir](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html):

```
   #define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
   #include <dirent.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int
   main(void)
   {
       struct dirent **namelist;
       int n;

       n = scandir(".", &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
       if (n == -1) {
           perror("scandir");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       while (n--) {
           printf("%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);
           free(namelist[n]);
       }
       free(namelist);

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

A `ls` program would iterate for each argument, see if it's a file - if it is, list it with permissions (one call to `stat` + formatting). If an argument is a dir - it would use `scandir` then `stat` for each file + formatting. Note that the [output format of ls](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html#tag_04_81_10) is actually specified in some cases (but still leaves much freedom to implementations).

> How can I list all "*.txt" files in a directory in good old C?

There's another example in [man-pages glob](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html). The code would be just simple:

```
       glob_t globbuf = {0};
       glob("*.txt", 0, NULL, &globbuf);
       for (char **file = globbuf.gl_pathv; *file != NULL; ++file) { 
               printf("%s\n", *file);
       }
       globfree(&globbuf);
```

The POSIX links and linux-man pages project are great for studing - linux-man pages has that `SEE ALSO` section below that is great for discovering functions. Also see [GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Calling-Glob.html).

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the shell expanding the globs itself (this explain why I did not see this in the linked code). I was aiming for using `opendir` since I found an alternative on Windows (https://github.com/tronkko/dirent/) - now I need to find an alternative for glob on windows .

Comment: I know nothing about windows - on windows, I would install mingw+cygwin, then be happy with a POSIX environment.